# How to query for Polkadot transaction info using only txHash?

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

I cannot find any description on how to get the transaction info using just the txHash returned by signAndSend() in the API documentation. I think it's a basic function which is really weird that it's not there.

As I can see the only way to track the status of a transaction is using the callback functions of signAndSend() which only viable if the transaction was created from my side. However in block explorers like polkadot.subscan.io or polkascan.io, I can easily find the transaction using just the txHash. Any idea just briefly on how can I implement such a function?

Comment: Hashes are not used to uniquely identify transactions on Substrate-based chains. On Substrate-based chains, transactions are identified by a tuple containing the block in which the transaction was submitted and the index (position) of that transaction in the list of transactions associated with that block.

Comment: @DanForbes I see, but somehow exchanges like to returned to the users only the txHash. And I can see the way to easily pick up just my transfer even if it's in a batch extrinsic. The problem is no exchange give back the unique identification in the format of blockNumber-index

Comment: You may want to look into something like Substrate Archive, which is probably the type of thing block explorers and exchanges may use as a middle layer between the actual blockchain and the application capabilities that are exposed to users https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-archive

Comment: @DanForbes that might be what I'm looking for. Previously I was just concerned about listening for transactions' status could end unexpectedly somehow. That would make it unreliable to get the common blockNumber + index identification. The only thing we could have left is the txHash which was returned right away. Thank you very much! Could you make an answer so I can mark it solved my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please consider using a solution such as [Substrate Archive](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-archive) to help you index transactions on a Substrate-based chain.